# Creating raster that counts points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, arcgis-10.4, count

Is there a way to create a raster that counts points?

I have dresses (points) and I want to know how many addresses are in a square of 100m. So I also need a tool t measure one meter. I think it is quite simple, but I don't even now how this tool should be called. I'm using ArcGIS 10.4 on a Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the point density tool in ArcGIS.  Here is a link to the tool http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/point-density.htm
Set your output cell size to 1 meter and the neighborhood settings to 100 m square.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a grid of 1m squares, try the [grid index features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-grid-index-features.htm) tool. Then calculate the [Zonal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-geometry-as-table.htm) to determine the sum (or count) of the points within each of the grid cells. You can then join the new statistics table to the grid and symbolize, etc as necessary.